# How to extract all bold words of PDF file using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, attributes, pdftotext, bold

I want a list of all bold words from a PDF file to be written into a txt/docx file using Python.

This is what I've tried:

```
document = Document('C:/Users/KRR/Desktop/resume.pdf')
bolds=[]
italics=[]
for para in document.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        if run.bold :
            bolds.append(run.text)
```